# Javascript : extract String between last two specific characters

Tags: javascript

I have strings in which each word is followed by a point like this examples
**example 1:** `I.love.watching.movies.`
**example2:** `hello.I.am.a.football.fan.`
I want to extract the last word followed by its point for example in **example 2** I want to extract the string `fan.`
How to achieve this ?

Comment: you can `use string.split();` to separate strings by any character

Comment: I mean extract, I corrected it

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`String#match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match).

```js
let str = 'hello.I.am.a.football.fan.';
let res = str.match(/.*?\./g).pop();
console.log(res);
```

Explanation of the [regex](https://regex101.com/r/Fr2sTp/1):

- `.*?`: Matches any character, except the line terminators, any number of times, lazily.
- `\.`: Matches the character, `.`.

Comment: I understand what pop does but can you please explain in a simple manner what match() does

Comment: @coldprogrammmer Since the `g` flag is used, it returns all results matching the complete regular expression. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match

Comment: what *?\ mean in this regex

Comment: Match any character zero or more times lazily. You can put it into regex101.com and it'll give you a complete explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the index of the one-but-last point, and then slice the string that follows it:

```js
let str = 'hello.I.am.a.football.fan.';
let i = str.lastIndexOf(".", str.length - 2); // second argument to skip last point
console.log(str.slice(i+1));
```